# accessing pandas dataframe from one file into another file

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 files wherein in one file i have created two functions. In the first function I have created a dataframe. and i am using that dataframe as an input into another file. For eg

file1.py

```
def function1():
    df = pd.Dataframe()
def function2(df):
    return df.
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import function1,function2
return function2(df)
```

The error says: NameError: name 'df' is not defined

I am running file2.py first which calls functions from file1.py

Answer (score 0):

There are two things

1. You already returning the function2 then there is no need to return it again.Just call the function.In your case it should be function2(df)
2. You need dataframe which needs to be passed to the function2 as in your original function you are just passing the argument as df, so you need to pass the dataframe to your function2.

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this code using your csv file

```
#file1.py

import pandas as pd


def fun1():
    path=r"csv file path"
    df=pd.read_csv(path)
    data=pd.DataFrame(df)

    #print(data)
    return data

def fun2():

    data=fun1()
    print(data)
    return data
```

now call fun1 from fun2 and call fun2 from another file which is file2.py and also you can call fun1 from file2.py

```
from file1 import fun1,fun2

#call fun1 from file2.py
data=fun1()
print(data)

#call fun2 from file2.py
data=fun2()
print(data)
```